# When I use SHAP for classification problem, it shows an output that is not 0 or 1. How can I overcome this?

Tags: classification, xgboost

I'm using Pima Indians Diabetes Database(https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database). I made predictions using XGboost and I'm trying to analyze the features using SHAP.

However when I use force_plot with just one training example(a 1x8 vector) it shows that my output is -2.02. This is a classification problem, I shouldn't be seeing such a value. I'm new in SHAP and I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn as skl
import shap

dataset=np.loadtxt("diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
X=dataset[:,0:8]
Y=dataset[:,8]
seed=7
test_size=0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=skl.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

shap.initjs()
model=xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions=model.predict(X_test)
accuracy=skl.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(accuracy*100)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:].reshape(1, 8), X_train[0,:].reshape(1, 8))
```

Accuracy of my model is: 77,95.

[image: Here is the result of my plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default link function is the identity, so you are seeing log-odds rather than probabilities. To see the probability, try adding `link='logit'` to your call of `force_plot` like so:

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value,
                shap_values[0,:].reshape(1, 8),
                X_train[0,:].reshape(1, 8),
                link='logit')
```

You can read more at the [SHAP documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#shap.force_plot) site.

Comment: I did what you sad, I see 0.12 now as my output. Does it means my output is 0?

Comment: That would mean that the probability output by the model is 0.12. If you are using 0.5 as a cutoff, then your prediction is 0. But note that you can use any cutoff value that you'd like. This is what gives rise to the ROC curve and AUC metric.